# How to keep class which implement an interface with annotation

Tags: java, proguard

I defined an annotation named `@KeepAll`.

I have an interface like

```
@KeepAll
public interface MainEntity {
    //some methods
}
```

I want to keep all classes which implement this interface from obfuscation. Is this possible on ProGuard?

**NOTE** I know I can define it as

```
-keep public class * implements **.MainEntity
```

But I don't want to specify interface name but annotation name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long trial and error process I get what I want. Here is the solution

Keep class names with annotation KeepAll;

```
-keep @com.package.name.KeepAll public class **
```

Keep class members of classes and interface with annotation KeepAll;

```
-keepclassmembers @com.package.name.KeepAll class ** { public <methods>; <fields>;}
```

Keep class members of a class which implemets a class that has KeepAll annotation. (This was what I want)

```
-keepclassmembers public class * implements @com.package.name.KeepAll ** { public <methods>; <fields>;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can tell ProGuard to keep everything with an annotation like this:

`-keep @com.google.inject.Singleton public interface *`

The above would keep the interface itself from obfuscation.

To get the implementations of the interface you can do something like this:

```
-keep public class * implements **.MainEntity
```

So Right now I am confused what you want to achieve. If you only annotate the interface it wont be a help for ProGuard. The classes would need this annotation.

Comment: @xxlali then be more specific. There are only two options. use `keep` on the keyword `implements` or on the annotation. However the classes would have to be annotated then and not the interface

Comment: I want to say 2 things: First : "Don't obfuscate interfaces and classes with KeepAll annotation". I know how to do that. Also you have given example of this. Second thing is: "Don't obfuscate classes and interfaces which extends or implements a class or interface which have KeepAll annotation". I hope I could be more specific