# Proguard Error- NoSuchMethodException in EnumTypeInt

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have an interface named EnumInt and using it as below

```
                 case EnumInt:
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Class<? extends EnumInt> enumType = (Class<? extends EnumInt>) field.getType();
                        Method enumStaticMethod = enumType.getMethod("fromVal", int.class);
                        Object enumInstance = enumStaticMethod.invoke(null, object);
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(entity, enumInstance);
                        break;
```

I have already keep whole package in progaurd but still getting

> -keep class abc.cde.** { *; } // package having EnumInt interface and other files

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fromVal [int]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
```

I have tried Keeping EnumInt Interface, All native method, fields in proguard for preventing obfuscation but still unable to remove error.
Please note without proguard it is working fine.
Please help. Thanks in advance. Problem is specific to Enums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep class which implement an interface with annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833694/how-to-keep-class-which-implement-an-interface-with-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the future readers.
I was using another enum implementing EnumInt like below

```
public static enum CustomeType implements EnumInt {
    ALL(MSG_TYPE_ALL),
    IN(MSG_TYPE_IN),
    OUT(MSG_TYPE_OUT),

    int val;

    private CustomeType(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static CustomeType fromVal(int val) {
        for (CustomeType messageType : values()) {
            if (messageType.val == val) {
                return messageType;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and i was missing the proguard obfuscation to prevent this enum.

**Solution**

Below line in proguard

```
-keep public enum abc.cde.a.CustomeType$** {
**[] $VALUES;
 public *;
 }
```